# Limits of greatest integer function

Tags: calculus

[image: I thought that i can solve it by writing this as Riemann sum.]
!
! I thought that i can solve it by writing this as Riemann sum. I am stuck now. I want hints not solution as well as reference wikis to master such problems. I know basics  of greatest integer functions and simple integration of it , but cant solve tricky questions of summation and etc. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;k^2 x \le \lfloor k^2x \rfloor \lt k^2x+1\,$ by the definition of the greatest integer function , therefore:

$$x \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2x \;\le\;\; \sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k^2x \rfloor \;\;\lt\; \sum_{k=1}^n ( k^2x + 1) = x \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 +n$$

Replacing $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\,$ and dividing by $n^3$:

$$x \cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6 n^3} \;\le\;\; \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor k^2x \rfloor \;\;\lt\; x \cdot \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6 n^3} + \frac{1}{n^2}$$

The limit then follows by the squeeze theorem since  $\lim \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$ and $\lim \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6 n^3}$ exists.

Comment: Do I need to use squeeze theorem ..By that i got x/3 as answer. Am i correct

Comment: @Sourav That's correct. I edited my answer to correct for the squares ($k^2$ instead of $k$), which I had originally mistaken for some sort of checkmarks. That's one more reason why [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) works better.

Comment: Thanks. If i take LHS as $k^ 2 -1$, I can get same answer. Do i always need to take $k^2$

Comment: @Sourav I noticed you did that in the (now deleted) answer, and it is technically correct since $a-1 \lt a \le \lfloor a \rfloor \implies a-1 \lt \lfloor a \rfloor\,$, but the inequality I used looks more natural to me.